# Parsing HTML to json object

Tags: javascript, html

So I am looking to create a script to return certain values from a JSON. Part of this JSON object I have is HTML. How do I parse the HTML so I can use it in a JSON object?

This is the HTML:

```
<span style="color:#800000">protected</span></div></div>
<div><div><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:150%">wummie</span><br /><span style="font-size:105%">Independent Faction</span><br /><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:110%">woman</span><br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">SlowlyWastingAway:</span> Deusphage<br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Member Count:</span> 1<br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Age:</span> 2 years, 5 months and 6 days<br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Bank:</span> 0 Regals<br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Flags:</span><br /><span style="color:#800000">open</span> | <span style="color:#800000">monsters</span> | <span style="color:#008000">animals</span><br />
```

How would I parse it so it is like:
wummie
Independent Faction
woman

SlowlyWastingAway: Deusphage

Member Count: 1
Age: 2 years, 5 months and 6 days
Bank: 0 Regals

Flags:
open | monsters | animals

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a standard answer but it works.

```
var a=document.createElement("div")
a.innerHTML=`<span style="color:#800000">protected</span></div></div>
<div><div><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:150%">wummie</span><br /><span style="font-size:105%">Independent Faction</span><br /><span style="font-style:italic;font-size:110%">woman</span><br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">SlowlyWastingAway:</span> Deusphage<br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Member Count:</span> 1<br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Age:</span> 2 years, 5 months and 6 days<br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Bank:</span> 0 Regals<br /><br /><span style="font-weight:bold">Flags:</span><br /><span style="color:#800000">open</span> | <span style="color:#800000">monsters</span> | <span style="color:#008000">animals</span><br />`
.replace(/<br \/>/g,"\n")
```

then `a.innerText` is what you want